# How do you move from stock Relay to Relay with a router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, react-router-relay

I have a React/Relay app that is currently working that I would like to add routing to using react-router-relay.  When I try the minimum possible conversion, see the code below, I get an incomprehensible error in the log: "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: RelayQueryNode: Invalid concrete node."

```
import 'babel/polyfill';
import TodoApp from './components/TodoApp';

import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import ReactRouterRelay from 'react-router-relay';
import TodoAppHomeRoute from './routes/TodoAppHomeRoute';

/*

This section works perfectly

ReactDOM.render(
  <Relay.RootContainer Component={TodoApp} route={new TodoAppHomeRoute()} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
*/


//This breaks every time.
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router
    createElement={ReactRouterRelay.createElement}>
    <Route
      path="/"
      component={TodoApp}
      queries={new TodoAppHomeRoute().queries} // and the query
      />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Another possible way to phrase this question would be: What are the differences between the appropriate ways to specify plain vanilla Relay's RelayRoutes.queries and react-router-relay's queries for Routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of other people reported this issue [here](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay/issues/35).

Looks like adding an explicit `import` for each of `Relay` and `React` *in your components* may fix it (I was seeing this just now and it fixed it for me):

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
```

Or failing that, an `npm install --save react react-relay graphql graphql-relay react-dom` to update your dependencies.

Comment: Yup, that's the bug, thanks for finding that github issue for me. I either didn't find it or it didn't exist yet when I created the StackOverflow question. It does seem odd that an unused import would fix the problem. An interesting architectural choice...

Comment: I followed up with [this fix](https://github.com/facebook/relay/commit/72580206f1e8eb790f78a6b4ffa3c2803d9654b6) making all the imports in the examples (and a corresponding commit in the starter kit) to make it less likely that people will get stung by this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If Chris's answer didn't work, @cpojer wrote up a really awesome posts about routes and Relay here: https://medium.com/@cpojer/relay-and-routing-36b5439bad9

Comment: Thanks Yuzhi, unfortunately that article is where I started and contains a number of errors already due I suspect to the pace that respective teams are iterating on their libraries. My above example is very close to what the Medium article suggests but doesn't work for reasons I have yet to divine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `new TodoAppHomeRoute().queries` is the offender. My hunch is that it's probably a static property. Try this `TodoAppHomeRoute.queries`.

If that doesn't work, let's see the code in `TodoAppHomeRoute`